# Retrofit, top level json object changes name

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit to make an api call. The top level object is named depending on the query parameters of the request. For example, a request like this:

`api.somewebsite.com/1.0/mix_info?mix_id=69`

returns a response like this:

```
{"69":{
    "mix_id":"69",
    "mix_title":"A Title",
    "mix_file":"https:example.com/mp3",
    "mix_genres":"House,Pop",
    "mix_dj_id":"57",
    "number_votes":"390",
    "station":"1" 
    }
}
```

Heres a screenie as well that kinda shows the format:
http://prnt.sc/axltcd

Basically, depending on the number passed into the url `mix_id=` query becomes the name of the top level json object returned in the response.

I was able to hack together something that kinda works:

I have a model Response class which has a member variable that is the top level object, and I use Retrofit's @SerializedName("69") to explicity set the name. This, of course, will only work for a request with the id of 69, otherwise the response returns null object.

It looks like this:

```
public class Response {

     @SerializedName("69")
     private _69 _69;
}
```

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to properly handle these oddly formatted responses. How would this be done?

Comment: What about serializing a HashMap?

Comment: Well `hashMap.put('yourKey', yourData); serialize(hashMap)`

Comment: What your suggesting makes no sense.

Comment: It may not make any sense as I've never done any of this and know nothing about Retrofit, but my point is that if you were serializing a HashMap rather than a Response then I'm pretty sure it would get properly serialized by default. Otherwise you will propably have to configure a custom serializer (check the docs).

Comment: Tried to use `HashMap<String, Model>` to deserialize response? Then You should be able get values from this map with `entrySet()`.

Comment: I sort of see where you going with this. I made the call return a <HashMap<String, Response>>, but in my onResponse callback how do I pull out the proper object. Eg. What would be the key for the object in the map?

Comment: Edit: Ok this works. Why does this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive your response as JsonElemen, convert it to JsonObject and get element by global variable which you was using for send request.

Response:

```
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
         JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
         JsonObject jObj= jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
         JsonObject number= jObj.get(CONSTANT_WHICH_YOU_USED_FOR_REQEST).getAsJsonObject();
}
```

Feel free to ask me if any.